# Execute Custom Java Sonar rules using junits

Tags: sonarqube

I have a requirement to execute Java Custom Sonar rules using JUnit(not by Sonar runner or any tool).

For e.g.,
if there are list of custom plugins. I want to execute these rules using JUnit's APIs provided by Sonar against any project, like,
JavaCheckVerifier.verify("MyClass.java", new MyCustomPlugin());

Is this possible?

Comment: There would be a possibility to do that, but then the question would be : why on earth would you want to do this (except for testing your custom plugin) ? This would be hacking around the SonarJava analyzer API to get things called from a Junit test and I struggle to see where the value out of this would be. So : what _exactly_ are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure the answer to that is no. A Sonar custom role is designed to be run on Sonar. Do you know (or can you find out) why there is a "requirement" to run the rules with JUnit? This sounds like a "requirement" made with assumptions about the implementation.

A better requirement would be to be able to find out about static analysis failures in a build. Or at test time. Or something else.

Comment: Yes, the requirement is made with assumption. We want to execute Sonar rules without having Sonar set up. It should be as simple as download Sonar dependency and execute the rules with out any set up.

Comment: It seems like you'd choose to use Sonar if you want the Sonar rules. Or use an open source tool like PMD if you don't want to use Sonar. That's why I asked about the real requirement. Which might be that you want to know the result of certain rules that Sonar happens to have implemented.